# How do I install turbo c++?

Tags: package-management

I am used to Turbo C++ and I am new to Ubuntu.

I really need Turbo C++ to get started.

Can somebody please help me to install Turbo C++ on Ubuntu.

Comment: Turbo c++ is a stone age ide+compiler, you can't create a modern os app using turbo c++, so try a modern c++ ide like codeblocks, qtcreator etc :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To run Turbo C++ in Ubuntu you must have the following:

**A.Turbo C++ setup**
   If you have the setup then excellent

**B.DOSBox Emulator**
   If you have it installed on your system the good but if you don't go to
**Ubuntu Software Center** and search for DOSBox and install the emulator.

or using terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install dosbox
```

Now follow these steps...

**1.Extract the rar file and you'll get a setup folder.**

If you don't have `unrar` utility you just need to install small package called " unrar "

Step 1 : goto your Terminal  then type

```
sudo apt-get install unrar
```

you can now extract your .RAR file by "right-click" then chose " extract here "

or via terminal

```
 unrar dosbox.rar
```

Move the extracted folder to your home folder

**2.Open the DOSBox emulator**

Write the following commands :

```
   1.mount c ~
   2.C:
   3.cd setup
   4.install.exe
```

**3.The turbo C++ installation utility will appear**.**Press Enter**.

Enter the source drive as C.**Press Enter.**

Change the source path to \setup if it isn't.**Press Enter.**

**4.Select Start Installation and Press Enter.**

The installer will install the files.Once finished u can delete the
   setup folder.

**5.To run the Turbo C++ every time run the following commands:**

```
   1.mount c ~
   2.C:
   3.cd tc\bin
   4.tc.exe
```

To enter into fullscreen mode press 
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and press it again for window mode.

[source](http://bharatflake.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-instal-turbo-c-in-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 4):

The Borland Turbo C++ compiler is no longer available. On Linux, a C++ compiler is provided by the GNU Compiler Collection, which you can get by installing the 'build-essential' package. Many Ubuntu applications are actually written in C++.

You can edit your code with a simple editor (e.g. Gedit) and complile from the command line (command g++). Or you can install an IDE, of which there are many to choose from. I'm not a C programmer, but people seem to like Eclipse CDT (package 'eclipse-cdt').

If you have a body of Turbo C++ code that you want to reuse, it will probably be necessary to convert it. The Turbo C++ libraries may not be supported by GCC. I can't really help you there, but you can probably find help for specific cases on the Internet.

Answer (score 3):

Although may be possible to use Turbo C++ in Linux i think you are best served with native linux tools. In Linux the most common C/C++ compiler is `gcc`/`g++`. A basic development setup can be achieved installing `build-essential` package.

If you need an IDE to write yours C/C++ programs you have many choices:

- [Eclipse C/C++ Dev. tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/eclipse-cdt/)
- [Anjuta IDE](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/anjuta/)
- [Code::Blocks](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/codeblocks/)
- [...](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/department/developer-tools/)

As i said unless you really need to use Turbo C++, give a try on those tools. You will have a much more modern development system with more features.

Answer (score 3):

### Turbo C++ installation with problem solving

I finally fixed my problem. I was trying to run "Turbo C++" in Ubuntu and I was facing a problem and then I solved it. Please read this to the end.

#### Installation

-Open "*terminal*".

- Type `sudo apt-get install dosbox` to install DOSBox.
- When it is installed download TC (download this Turbo C++), extract it, and paste it in home directory.

  [image]
- Type `dosbox` in the terminal to open it.
- Create a configuration file by typing this command in the DOSBox console.

  ```
  config -writeconf dosbox.conf
  ```

[Note: By default dosbox.conf file is created in the home directory.]

Write these commands in  the DOSBox console.

```
mount c ~
```

or

```
mount c ~ /home/your_username/
c:
cd tc/bin
tc.exeortc
```

Now, when I tried "tc.exe". it was just getting closed/crashed and showing this in the terminal.

```
DOSBox switched to max cycles, because of the setting: cycles=auto.   
If the game runs too fast try a fixed cycles amount in DOSBox's options.

Exit to error: DRC64:Unhandled memory reference `
```

#### Fix Problem shown in terminal

I did this and everything is working fine:

1. Open "dosbox.conf" present in your home folder.

   [image]
2. Change things like this:

   ```
   core=normal
   cputype=normal
   cycles=normal
   ```

   [image]

or if you want you can try "simple" instead of "normal", but "normal" works fine.

This is it. Save and Exit "dosbox.confi" and then start your DOSBox again.

#### Auto-run Turbo C++

After fixing your problem. Whenever you open DOSBox. Every time you have to mount it and this is a big headache. For solving this follow this:

- Open "dosbox.confi"
- Go at the bottom and add these commands for your Turbo C++ auto-run in DOSBox.

  ```
  mount c ~ /home/prince
  c:
  cd tc
  cd bin
  tc
  ```

  [image]

and Save & Exit and now run and test it.

#### Full screen problem

That is all. It was not in fullscreen mode. That is why I changed this thing:

```
fullscreen=true
fulldouble=false
fullresolution=your computer resolution
windowresolution=your computer resolution
output=overlay
autolock=false
```

[image]

and for finding your computer resolution. Open the terminal and type this:

```
xdpyinfo | grep 'dimensions:'
```

[image]

Comment: btw your desktop icons in the last screenshot look horrible because they are too large. To fix this problem open Files, click the 3 parallel lines icon on the Files toolbar, and reset the Zoom to a smaller %. You should make the last screenshot again and re-upload it to your GitHub page after doing that.

Comment: Sorry dud. But my mom was getting angry on me because I was previously playing Clash Royal then Clash of Kings and then running computer from 2 hour. That is why I didn't get much time have a more answer

Comment: But even though, Did my first post was helpful ???

Comment: **I don't know anything about github.** I just get a challenge from my school's computer teacher to run Turbo C++ using Dos box Emulator in Ubuntu and I did this all. I only know exploring internet and LOL.

Comment: I've seen several of these kinds of answers and I liked all of them except for the ones where they used a phone to take screen photos instead of screenshots. As long as the answer looks OK, people will read it. Otherwise they will downvote it.

Comment: Maybe lack of knowledge is the reason. As you know Development is more Important then Growth.

Comment: I like more knowledge in short notes. I am school student and I have stay focused on my studies. But, my laptop is my life. And Internet is my Life's heart beat. I only get access of Internet for 1 or 2 hours and I have so-many things in my mind. That is why I try to get more simple answers then read a long script on a single thing. Hope your future posts may be positively affected by problems ...

Answer (score 1):

A very intuitive guide for installing `Turbo c++` on `Ubuntu system` is [here](https://solancer.blogspot.com/2011/05/turbo-c-on-ubuntu-using-dosbox.html?showComment=1573399940762#c2661983187837093152).

Answer (score 0):

You can download Turbo C++ Compiler from the given link below.

http://www.4shared.com/zip/R96sJOwq/Turbo_C_for_Windows.html

To run this compiler you need Wine installed on your Ubuntu desktop/server.

Just install Wine and unpack the downloaded turbo compiler.

Double click the .exe file or right click and choose 'open with wine windows program loader'

The the file will ask to install, install the setup and search for 'turboc++' in unity.

Click and run the application, this will open the compiler in full screen mode.

---

To exit the compiler....

Select File>Quit (Alt+X)

That's all you will be back to the Ubuntu desktop.