# How do I install Turbo C or Code::Blocks?

Tags: software-installation, code-blocks

How can I install Turbo C or Code::Blocks on Ubuntu? I am new to Ubuntu so please explain step-by-step.

I tried to write a program in Gedit, but could not find out how to run and execute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code::Blocks**

Just open the Ubuntu Software Center and search for its name.

Or install via the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks
```

Source : [How to install the Code::Blocks IDE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198442/how-to-install-code-block)

**To run Turbo C++ in Ubuntu you must have the following:**

**A**.Turbo C++ setup If you have the setup then excellent

**B**.DOSBox Emulator If you have it installed on your system the good but if you don't go to Ubuntu Software Center and search for DOSBox and install the emulator.

or using terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install dosbox
```

**Now follow these steps...**

**1**.Extract the rar file and you'll get a setup folder.

If you don't have unrar utility you just need to install small package called `" unrar "`

**Step 1** : goto your Terminal then type

```
sudo apt-get install unrar
```

you can now extract your .RAR file by "right-click" then chose " extract here "

or via terminal

```
 unrar dosbox.rar
```

Move the extracted folder to your home folder

2.Open the DOSBox emulator

Write the following commands :

```
   1.mount c ~
   2.C:
   3.cd setup
   4.install.exe
```

3.The turbo C++ installation utility will appear.*Press Enter*.

Enter the source drive as C.Press Enter.

Change the source path to \setup if it isn't.Press Enter.

4.Select Start Installation and Press Enter.

The installer will install the files.Once finished u can delete the setup folder.

5.To run the Turbo C++ every time run the following commands:

```
 1.mount c ~
   2.C:
   3.cd tc\bin
   4.tc.exe
```

To enter into fullscreen mode press Alt+Enter and press it again for window mode.

Sources:
http://bharatflake.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-instal-turbo-c-in-ubuntu.html
[How do I install turbo c++?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198477/how-do-i-install-turbo-c)