# This program cannot be run in DOS mode

Tags: dosbox

I tried installing Tutbo C++ on Ubuntu 17.10. I followed the process in [How do I install turbo c++?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198477/how-do-i-install-turbo-c)

[image]

But it gave me the and error : "This program cannot be run in DOS mode"

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

This error is probably due to wrong version of setup.exe of the Turbo C++. Usually windows programs give this message when trying to run in DOS environment.

You can try to run the setup using wine:

```
wine setup.exe
```